# DefaultNetworkCredentials or DefaultCredentials

Tags: .net, credentials, defaultnetworkcredentials

Which one am I supposed to use when I need to supply a credential to a proxy (local or in Network)?

What's the exact difference between these two?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

They are exactly the same thing, which you can confirm for yourself using a disassembler like Reflector. The only difference is that `DefaultNetworkCredentials` returns a `NetworkCredentials` object and and `DefaultCredentials` casts it to `ICredentials`. So you have access to more information with a NetworkCredentials object, but which of those you use supply to an object requiring an ICredentials instance makes no difference, since it's the same object instance: `object.ReferenceEquals(CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials, CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials)` returns `true`.

Answer (score 15):

The difference between the two is very subtle. DefaultNetworkCredentials is the newer of the two (added with .NET 2.0), and the core difference is that under certain security conditions, it can expose more private information about the logged-in user to the application. For more information, try this blog post:

http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/archive/2004/07/28/199706.aspx

Comment: Link is broken. I believe this is the blog post referenced: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/buckh/authentication-in-web-services-with-httpwebrequest/